# Reading a csv file in using pandas csv_read in a for loop

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, for-loop

I am using Macbook with MAC OS X catalina and the latest anaconda installation.

I have a list of files I want to be read in a folder I have with many files. The list of files are contained in an excel sheet in the following format.

[image: list.xlsx]

This file is called list.xlsx

The directory and sub directories of csv files are located in a folder as follows `"/Users/XXX/Documents/test/data"`

There are many other files in the directory which I don't want to use, therefore I want to cycle through this list.xlsx of files I have.

When I do `df = pd.csv_read("/Users/XXX/Documents/test/data/A/ABCS.csv")`, the file is read perfectly fine. This is the first file in my list.

However, when I load the file this way, so I can perform a for loop,

```
filelist = pd.read_excel("/Users/XXX/Documents/test/list.xlsx")

df = pd.csv_read(f"/Users/XXX/Documents/test/data/{filelist.File[0]}")
```

I get a `'FileNotFoundError: [Error 2] File /Users/XXX/Documents/test/data/A/ABCS.csv does not exist:/Users/XXX/Documents/test/data/A/ABCS.csv'`

Even though it shows the exact location I used above. Why is this happening and how do I fix it? It seems that when I load the file names using pandas, it can't be read properly.

Comment: Do not blindly trust a printed string, but dump it in hexa to make sure it does not contain non printable characters. Please show what gives `print([(i, hex(ord(i))) for i in filelist.File[0]])`

Comment: it says <generator object <genexpr> at 0x121ea4a50>

Comment: Oops, my bad. I wrote mere parens when square brackets are required for a list...

Comment: you helped me figure it out, thanks, there were a bunch of whitespaces which i couldnt see.

Comment: please post an answer or something if you want

Comment: I cannot post a answer myself now, so please feel free to post one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serge Ballesta said I should not blindly trust the printed string, I ran the command  print([(i, hex(ord(i))) for i in filelist.File[0]]) as he suggested and found there were a string of spaces after the file names which was messing up the read function.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a work around:

```
filelist = pd.read_excel("/Users/XXX/Documents/test/list.xlsx")
DF = []
for i in range(len(filelist)):
    file = str(filelist[i])
    df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None, header=0)
    DF.append(df)

#combine all files
DF = pd.concat(DF, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```